# Proof related to circle

Tags: geometry, circles

How can I prove that if two circles, one entirely inside the other, intersect at a point, then that point of intersection must be collinear with the centers of the two circles?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. What have you tried yourself to prove this? Also, I've taken the liberty of editing your post for clarity. Please ensure I've correctly preserved the intent of your question.

Comment: Can 2 such circles really intersect or should it be $\mathbf{TOUCH}$?

Comment: Only should be TOUCH

Answer (score 5):

By symmetry: mirror the two circles around the line that joins the centers. This leaves the circles unchanged, and so must remain the intersection, so it is on the axis.

Answer (score 0):

Let the radii be AB and and PB. So AB  can be written as AP+PB= which proves the collinearity othese 3 points thus both the radii lie on the same line and and the point too. Theres no rigorous proof for this Sorry.